# How do I get the number of numbers in a text in R?

Tags: r

I want to know how many digits do I have in a text variable. For example, a function that in the text "ABC234" the answer would be 3.

I tried with this:

```
aa=gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]*","ABC234")
```

I almost have [it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zysA2.png), but honestly I still dont understand the lists, so I have no idea how to get it.

Any function? Or how to manage it with my almost-option?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match each digit and then take the length of the returned value:

```
lengths(gregexpr("\\d", "ABC234"))
## [1] 3
```

or replace each non-digit with a zero length string and take the length of what remains:

```
nchar(gsub("\\D", "", "ABC234"))
## [1] 3
```

Answer (score 1):

As an option you can use `stringi` or `stringr` libraries as well:

```
stringi::stri_count('ABC234', regex = '\\d')
# [1] 3
stringr::str_count('ABC234', '\\d')
# [1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dpylr` and `readr` package as follows:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

string = "ABC234"
parse_number(string) %>% 
  nchar()

[1] 3
```